# How to calculate the number of nights using two dates in PHP

Tags: php

Here's my code.

```
$checkinDate = $_POST['checkinDate'];
$checkoutDate = $_POST['checkoutDate'];
$no_nights = date_diff($checkinDate, $checkoutDate);
```

My code error:

```
Warning: date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lgh-hms\admin\conformation.php on line 19
```

Comment: `checkinDate` and `checkoutDate` will have only date or date-time both ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Only dates sir.

Comment: @dadadaxtr, check A. Iglesias's answer, this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

date_diff needs date, not string...

Procedural style:

```
$checkinDate = date_create($_POST['checkinDate']);
$checkoutDate = date_create($_POST['checkoutDate']);
$interval = date_diff($checkinDate,$checkoutDate);
$no_nights = $interval->format('%a');
```

With Objects:

```
$checkinDate = new DateTime($_POST['checkinDate']);
$checkoutDate = new DateTime($_POST['checkoutDate']);
$interval = $checkinDate->diff($checkoutDate);
$no_nights = $interval->format('%a');
```

I hope it helps

Comment: My pleasure!! Have a nice day and happy coding!

Comment: it has error sir. 
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Comment: i'm just using date

Comment: What line is giving you that error? Show me what do you have in $_POST['checkinDate'] and $_POST['checkoutDate'], please

Comment: Yes, you're right! With date_diff you get a DateInterval object.I've edited the answer.

Comment: @A.Iglesias Doesn't work for `18-01-2019 16:00` (Friday) and `21-01-2019 08:00` (Monday). Returns 2, correct is 3 (nights).